# Does WxPack works with GCC 4.5/4.6 Series

Tags: wxwidgets

Hello I have installed TDM-GCC compiler suite for windows. Do i need to install MinGW 5.1.3 gcc 3.4.5 (candidate) to make wxpack work as said [here](http://wxpack.sourceforge.net/Tutorials/CodeBlocks)

Comment: Did you try? What happened? Errors?

Comment: No i didnt tried.. i am waiting for some response here. If wxwidgets really needs Mingw 5.1.3 then i will have to replace my old MingW!! W

Answer (score 1):

A late reply but here goes...
You can rebuild wxwidgets with whatever version you have I think.
In the build/msw directory you'll find a wxBuild_wxWidgets.bat file supporting
any number of compilers (I recompiled to match my VC++2008).
Near the top of the batch file are two variables, GCCDIR and GCC4DIR. Set the latter
to point to your GCC 4.x location. Then rebuild with

wxBuild_wxWidgets.bat MINGW4 ALL

It should work but I haven't tried it. On my old P4 Dell the build with VC90 took awhile.